# is there any horizontal scalable CEP(Complex event processing) engine available?

Tags: complex-event-processing

are there any Complex event processing systems available which can scale horizontally. or is it possible to implement such system with current available technologies

Answer (score 0):

Esper with Enterprise Edition comes to mind. The stack used there is based on Zookeeper and Kafka.

http://espertech.com/esper/faq_esper.php#scaling

http://www.espertech.com/products/esperee.php